# bootstrap carousel with full size centered image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to find the answer to this problem:

I want to create a carousel using bootstrap and when the user re-sizes the browser I want the image to remain at its original size but I also want the image to be centered.  How can this be done?

This is my attempt so far:

```css
.img-center {
  min-height: 720px;
  min-width: 1920px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="/img/beach1.jpg" alt="beach" class="img-center">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="/img/beach2.jpg" alt="beach" class="img-center">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put img into div with position relative, overflow hidden,and 100% width. Then position the img with left 50% and margin left minus half image width (ex. Img have 800px so minus margin should be 400). There you go.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to block the image to a certain height and width: Bootstrap carousel is responsive  so the best to work around it is to give your image a fix height and width:

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img{
       min-width:720px;
       min-height:1920px;
}
```

or

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img{
           width:720px;
           height:1920px;
}
```